# vector questions finding another line with the two given lines.

Tags: vectors, parametric

I have questions about this problem.
The vector equation of the lines L1 and L2 are r=(15,11,6)+t(6,3,2) and r=(0,7,-4)+s(-3,2,-6) respectively. Let A and B be the points on L1 and L2 with parameters t=0 and s=0 respectively.
Find the vector equation of the line L3 that passes point C (3,5,2) and is perpendicular to the plane ABC. Giving answer in parametric form.

Comment: Don't just post your homework problems with zero effort and expect us to do your homework for you. Show the work you've attempted and ask a specific question where you get stuck.

Comment: What are those questions you have about this problem?

Comment: Try to show your attempt.

Comment: You have 3 points, find the coordinate plane  plain they describe, Than you kow a perpendicular vector and the line is easy to find.

Comment: I got r=(3,5,2)+t(-22,24,21)